# Initializing square matrix in batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, matrix-multiplication

The task is to perform multiplication btw a vector of size (87236 x 1) and a lower triangular matrix of ones of size (87236 x 87236).

Since the lower triangular is very large in size, I can not initialize it to begin with.

I came across [tf.linalg.LinearOperationLowerTriangular()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/LinearOperatorLowerTriangular) operator, it ignores the upper triangular part of the matrix. Following is what I tried and it's output:

```
tril = tf.ones((4, 21809 , 21809)) 
lmt = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTriangular(tril)
x = tf.random.normal((87236, 1))
x = tf.reshape(x , (4, 21809,1))

lmt.matmul(x)
```

Following the error I got:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM 
when allocating tensor with shape[4,21809,21809] and type float on 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc 
[Op:MatrixBandPart]
```

Can I you suggest how can I perform this task efficiently? I guess performing it in batches is the solution, however how does one initialize a lower triangular matrix in batches?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is multiply two different matrix together try using this:

```
class Matrices:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.rows = len(self.matrix)
        self.columns = len(self.matrix[0])

    def multiply_matrices(self, other):
        """multiples 2 matrices together"""
        assert self.columns == other.rows, "Multiplying matrix rules not met"  # remove this line
        new_matrix_dimensions = (self.rows, other.columns)
        new_matrix = list()
            for a in range(self.rows):
                for b in range(other.columns):
                    value = 0
                    for c in range(other.rows):
                        value += self.matrix[a][c] * other.matrix[c][b]
                    new_matrix.append(round(value, 10))
        new_matrix = [new_matrix[i:i + new_matrix_dimensions[1]]
                  for i in range(0, len(new_matrix), new_matrix_dimensions[1])]
        return Matrices(new_matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the issue is that I can not initialize a matrix of this size, let alone perform matmul on it. Any thoughts on that??

Comment: My guess is that the library doesn't allow for initialization of a matrix of that size. The above code however, doesn't have those restrictions.